# How to isolate parts of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I [have a JSON](https://www.mediafire.com/?db4hbwcjwrchndi) that contains a backtest for various assets, I have separated the assets using the following code:

```
preds = 'test_predictions.json'

df = pd.read_json(preds)

asset = 'Poloniex_DOGE_BTC'

grouped = df.groupby('market_trading_pair')
print grouped.get_group(asset)

#each array should start and end: 
#start 1446012000
#end 1452556800
```

Now how can we truncate 'grouped' so that it starts and ends from the above timestamps ?

EDIT:

Sorry, here's an example of the df

```
  market_trading_pair  next_future_timestep_return  ohlcv_start_date  \
7073   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC                    -0.023256        1445392800   
7074   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC                     0.023810        1445396400   
7075   Poloniex_DOGE_BTC                     0.000000        1445400000   

   prediction_at_ohlcv_end_date  
7073                      0.999999  
7074                      1.000000  
7075                     -0.999891
```

Using Serbitar's answer:

i replaced `print grouped.get_group(asset)` with:

```
print grouped.get_group(asset)[['ohlcv_start_date'> 1446012000 ] & ['ohlcv_start_date'< 1452556800]]
```

[I get this error](http://pastebin.com/zd3n5bhe)

Comment: please include an example of your grouped dataframe

Comment: But what is your recommended output?

Answer (score 0):

its hard to judge if we do not have an example of your grouped dataframe.
if x is your starttime and y is your stoptime try:

```
grouped[(grouped.timestamp x) & (grouped.timestmap < y)]
```

you can also use the between function if you have an index on your timestamps.

Comment: Hello sorry i have pasted an sample

Comment: Hmm still throwing an error, any ideas ? `print grouped.get_group(asset)[('ohlcv_start_date'> 1446012000 ) & ('ohlcv_start_date'< 1452556800)]`